# IAR 8051 Embedded Workbench crashes if any options are changed

Tags: workbench, iar, 8051

If the Project > Options are changed in any way, the IAR IDE crashes. Version is 8.30.1
Also, when I exit out of debugging mode, the IAR IDE crashes.
It was working a week ago.

I tried installing a new instance of the IAR software.  It acts the same.

I tried searching for the command.xcl file in ..../AppData/Local/Temp and deleting it, as some have suggested elsewhere.  That file doesn't exist.

Banging my head against the wall for the last 5 hours would have been more enjoyable...

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Have you bought the license. Problem you are mentioning are related to trail version.
If its a premium one try contacting https://www.iar.com/support